# Arduino Wifi UDP begin Errors

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

After installing my library wifiudp and including it in my sketch it works fine. The moment I put `WifiUDP.begin` into my sketch, I get these errors. I go to my cpp file where the errors are referring to and I am unsure what I am supposed to do from there. Does anyone know? Thanks.

```
WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp.o: In function `WiFiUDP::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiUdp.cpp:93: undefined reference to `ServerDrv::insertDataBuf(unsigned char, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'
WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp.o: In function `WiFiUDP::endPacket()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiUdp.cpp:83: undefined reference to `ServerDrv::sendUdpData(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp.o: In function `WiFiUDP::beginPacket(IPAddress, unsigned int)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiUdp.cpp:74: undefined reference to `ServerDrv::startClient(unsigned long, unsigned int, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
WiFi1\WiFiUdp.cpp.o: In function `WiFiUDP::begin(unsigned int)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiUdp.cpp:25: undefined reference to `ServerDrv::startServer(unsigned int, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: It is clearly a linker error, because of 'undefined reference to'. I am not sure how to link on arduino though so go look up something like "arduino linker error"

Comment: So it seems the Github 'master' library for the UDP is all messed up. It kept interfering with the send command to send my data so i never got a blue light when i used the masters library and included the UDP. So i had to refer back to my old library that does correctly send data and open the masters one  with notepad++ and change a bunch of things not making sense in the masters library. The person who wrote it needs to test the send data and integrate it with the Udp calls because they dont work together. I have a WIFI library that works if anyone wants